# C++ Basic Functions

Tags: c++, function

I was assigned homework in my Programming class. I understand the gist of it but, I feel kinda lost. I would like some help and feedback on it.

My problem:
A particular talent composition has 5 judges, each of whom awards a score between 0 and 10 to each performer. Fractional scores, such as 8.3, are allowed. A performer's final score is determined by dropping the lowest and the highest score received, then averaging the 3 remaining scores. Write a program that uses this method to calculate a contestant's score. It should include the following functions:

double getJudgeData() should ask the user for a judge's score and validate the score. This function should be called 5 times from main, once for each of the 5 judges.
void calcScore() should calculate and display the average of the three scores that remain after dropping the highest and lowest scores the performer received. This function should be called once from main, and should be passed the 5 scores.
The last two functions, described below, should be called by calcScore, which uses the returned information to determine which of the scores to drop.

double findLowest() should find and return the lowest of the five scores passed to it.
double findHighest() should find and return the highest of the five scores passed to it.
Input validation: Do not accept judge scores lower than 0 or higher than 10.

I understand that the code to get the judges data will look something along the lines of

```
Double getJudgeData(double score){
    cout << "Judge, please enter your score";
cin >> score;
    while (score<0.0 || score> 10.0){
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one";
    cin>>score
    }
    return score;
    }
```

Basically that repeated 4 more times, for 5 times in total. I figured I'd just change the variable name to score1, score2 etc.
For the figuring out of the highest and lowest scores, I thought I could just use several if statements.
For example,

```
if (score < lowest)
    lowest=score;
else if (score1 < score)
    lowest = score1;
else if (score2 < score)
    lowest = score2;
else if (score3 < score)
    lowest = score3;
else if (score4 < score)
    lowest = score4;
```

and the opposite for the highest.

I guess my biggest problem is the coding for the void calcscore() and understanding all this. I feel like I don't totally understand it. Like I understand that I am using functions to find out the judges score in each case and sending the score back to main. BUt, I just don't feel like I understand what I am doing. I would like some guidance. Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*
Okay I've worked on my code some more and got up to here.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    double getJudgeData(double score) {

cout << "Judge 1 please enter your score: ";
cin >> score;

while (score < 0.0 || score > 10.0) {
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one" << endl;
    cin >> score;
}
return score;
}

      double getJudgeData1(double score1) {

cout << "Judge 2 please enter your score: ";
cin >> score1;

while (score1 < 0.0 || score1 > 10.0) {
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one" << endl;
    cin >> score1;
}
return score1;
}

     double getJudgeData2(double score2) {

cout << "Judge 3 please enter your score: ";
cin >> score2;

while (score2 < 0.0 || score2 > 10.0) {
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one" << endl;
    cin >> score2;
}
return score2;
}

     double getJudgeData3(double score3) {

cout << "Judge 4 please enter your score: ";
cin >> score3;

while (score3 < 0.0 || score3 > 10.0) {
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one" << endl;
    cin >> score3;
}
return score3;
}

double getJudgeData4(double score4) {

cout << "Judge 5 please enter your score: ";
cin >> score4;

while (score4 < 0.0 || score4 > 10.0) {
    cout << "Invalid score. Please enter a correct one" << endl;
    cin >> score4;
}
return score4;
}
     double findHighest(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4) {

double highest = score;
if (score1 > highest)
    highest = score1;
else if (score2 > highest)
    highest = score2;
else if (score3 > highest)
    highest = score3;
else if (score4 > highest)
    highest = score4;

return highest;

}

 double findLowest(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4) {

double lowest = score;
if (score1 < lowest)
    lowest = score1;
else if (score2 < lowest)
    lowest = score2;
else if (score3 < lowest)
    lowest = score3;
else if (score4 < lowest)
    lowest = score4;

return lowest;
    }


     void calcScore(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double highest, double lowest) {

double findHighest(highest);
double findLowest(lowest);
double avgScore = (score + score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 - lowest - highest) / 3;

cout << "\nThe contestant's average score is: " << avgScore << endl;
    }

    int main(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double highest, double lowest) {

getJudgeData(score);
getJudgeData1(score1);
getJudgeData2(score2);
getJudgeData3(score3);
getJudgeData4(score4);



system("PAUSE");

return 0;

}
```

It runs and is able to detect if a code is invalid on all the judges. It's just after It gets by all the inputs for the judges it will just say "press any key to continue" twice and end. It seems to not go through the void calcscore section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would collect the 5 scores in a vector.  Then calculate score would iterate them all, summing them, tracking the lowest/highest, and then subtract both from the sum.

Not going to write the code for you, but that seems like one good way to go about it.

Response to comment:

Then your min/max is going to have to be some sort of silliness like this:

```
double min(double a0, double a1, double a2, ...)
{
    double min = a0;

    if (a1 < min) min = a1;
    if (a2 < min) min = a2;
    ...

    return min;
}
```

Leave out the if or you won't get tail end parameters if any of the former are less than a0.

Comment: Didn't learn about Vectors or Arrays yet. I heard some of my Classmates saying how this would be easier if we had just done it using one of those two. This is my first programming class and still have a lot to learn.

Comment: So something like this would work for my lowest score?                                                                                                                  `double findLowest(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4) {

 double lowest = 10;

 if (score < lowest)
  lowest = score;
 else if (score1 < score)
  lowest = score1;
 else if (score2 < score)
  lowest = score2;
 else if (score3 < score)
  lowest = score3;
 else if (score4 < score)
  lowest = score4;

 return lowest;
}`

Comment: No.  Consider what happens when score2 is less than score and score3 is less than score2.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. I edited my version and believe this is correct.      `double findLowest(double score, double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4) {

 double lowest = score;
  if (score1 < lowest)
  lowest = score1;
 else if (score2 < lowest)
  lowest = score2;
 else if (score3 < lowest)
  lowest = score3;
 else if (score4 < lowest)
  lowest = score4;

 return lowest;
}`  Thank you so much for helping me this far and actively responding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the solution should revolve around

```
averageScore = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - findLowest() - findHighest()) / 3;
```

Which would allow you not to care about which score is lowest and highest, just about the values of highest and lowest scores.